# Tooltip.Связать вывод через content + атрибут title

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Как проще вывести имеющийся контент + атрибут title.Т.е чтобы было 'Привет + a.title' Есть идея сделать это через this

```
$( function() {
    $('.graize').tooltip({
      track: true,
      items: 'a',
      show: { effect: "blind"},
      content: function(){
        var p = this.title
        //получаю title, а с выводом проблемы...
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.graize').tooltip({
    track: true,
    items: 'a',
    show: { effect: "blind"},
    content: function() {return "Привет" + $(this).attr('title');}
});
```